# PC continually freezes

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, laptop, freeze

I have a HP Pavilion DV6 that my dad bought ~7 years ago. He only used it for about 2 years and as it had some issues he just stopped using it. Recently I took out the laptop and booted it up. It didn't charge and had some other issues. My dad spent some money to get it fixed up and upgraded it to Windows 10. It worked for really only 2 days. The computer started freezing, and I cold shut it down, it worked for some time, froze and I repeated the cycle for sometime. One time when it froze, it crashed and showed a :( blue screen and gave the code `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR`. So I searched online and found a guide that told me to enter `chkdsk /f /r` in cmd, and I don't know if it worked, but I was able to use it throughout the day, and I shut it down before going to sleep.

The next day it is getting stuck while starting, when the windows logo shows. I cold reboot it, then it goes into automatic repair, and then freezes. Same cycle. Now the thing is this problem is inconsistent. Sometimes it immediately freezes, sometimes it boots normally and when I get to the desktop it freezes, sometimes I can go into automatic repair, sometimes it freezes before I can even select some options.

My dad isn't willing to spend a lot of money on that laptop. My question is: Can it be saved? Is it done for? Can I do something to fix it or does it need fixing the hardware?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take it back to the person who "fixed it" as clearly they haven't.

Comment: Run the hard drive diagnostics from the bios, see if it finds any errors.